# How do I query previous 3 records in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I am building a simple login / register site for class. (ie no md5, sha, etc)  One of the parameters is to not let newly registered passwords be equal to previous 3 at the time of registration.  I was to write a function that returns true if this is the case.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  The primary key on my database is user_id (auto incremented).  here's a function that returns true if the username already exists:

```
function user_exists ($username) {
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) 
    FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;}
```

I thought I would start with this, and add some code to only look back at the previous three usernames

```
function returns true if password exists database
function password_exists ($password) {
$password = sanitize($password);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) `FROM `users` 
WHERE `password` = '$password' AND `user_id <'$user_id' ORDER BY user_id DESC, LIMIT 3"), 0) ==  1) ? true : false ;
```

Am I trying to do too much with one function?  ie do I need to first isolate the last 3 records in one function, then search that set?  should I add a column that numbers entries sequentially?  ie if there are 5 records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and '2' is deleted, the column would then read 1, 2, 3, 4.  it seems to me it would be easier to search that way.  any help greatly appreciated!  thanks

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by with a nested select of the form:

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT ...) as y;
```

Your inner select (SELECT ...) will return the records, ordered by date (most recent first) and with a LIMIT of 3.

Your outer select will select the username from the inner select.

If > 0 records are returned, you know the username is no good.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in doing this.
Either check against entire database or do not check at all.

Moreover, such a feature is going to be a huge impact to the security, means such an error can hint about someone's else password.

(if it's required by homework, no wonder why everyone hates PHP. Even in classes they teach you to write horrible code)